# How to remove 0% from pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pie-chart

I am working with text data to find the sentiment analysis. I have a data frame of sentiment score of each sentence. Using this data i am creating a pie chart but it shows the 0% in the graph. I am not able to understand the meaning of this 0%. Here is my data frame df1:

```
            score
Negative    100.0
Neutral     0.0
Positive    0.0
```

and here is my code for creating a pie chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
df1.plot(kind='pie', autopct='%1.1f%%', subplots=True,startangle=90,  legend = False, fontsize=14)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

and here is my output plot:

How can I remove this 0% from my plot?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, for a very 'actual' answer.

Then you give

```py
df1.plot(kind='pie', autopct='%1.1f%%', subplots=True,startangle=90,  legend = False, fontsize=14)
```

It takes full df with zeroes, like `[100,0,0]`
You can filter df, as un answer above but you can use lambda function in autopct as well:

```py
df1.plot(kind='pie', autopct=lambda p: '{:.1f}%'.format(round(p)) if p > 0 else '', subplots=True,startangle=90,  legend = False, fontsize=14)
```

Comment: How to add value along with percentage in that above code ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can just filter the dataframe to remove rows where `score` is zero.

```
df_to_plot = df1.loc[lambda df: df['score'] == 0]
```

Comment: What if I have many zeros in  all the columns in dataframes ?