# Python, How to add value along with percentage in pie plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have written a code to generate pie plot. In the autopct paramaters I followed [How to remove 0% from pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50449628/how-to-remove-0-from-pie-chart) this link to remove 0% which was showing up in plot. Now I want value along with the percentage. Can anyone please help me to fix this ?

```
for df_HPC_trial  in ((listofDF_hpc)):
    if len(df_HPC_trial)!= 0
        sum_column = df_HPC_trial.sum(axis=0,numeric_only=True)
        #print(sum_column)
        df_HPC_trial[df_HPC_trial.columns[2:]].sum().plot.pie(autopct=lambda p: '{:.1f}%'.format(round(p)) if p > 0 else '')
        plt.savefig('Figures/Reasons plot') 
        plt.close()
```

Comment: See this:[Labeling a pie and a donut](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-pie-and-donut-labels-py)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to create your own format to handle such issue.
Below is working example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def cust_format(x):
    print(x)
    return '{:.4f}%\n({:.0f})'.format(x, total*x/100)


values = pd.Series([False, False, True, True, True, True])
v_counts = values.value_counts()
total = len(values)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.pie(v_counts, labels=v_counts.index, autopct = cust_format, shadow=True)
```